# Reading from two files simultaneously in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file

I have an input text file "input.txt" that looks like this

```
Country Code ID QTY
FR  B000X2D 75 130
FR  B000X2E 75 150
```

I extract the data from each line as I will need to call another Ruby script with the arguments I extracted.

```
class Enumerator
  def enum_drop(n)
    with_index do |val, idx|
      next if n == idx
      yield val
    end
  end
end
#
f = File.open("input.txt", "r")
f.each_line.enum_drop(0) do |line|
   country, code = line.chomp.split(/\s+/)
   check = getInfo.new
   info = check.Info(country, code) 
   DO AS DESCRIBED BELOW
end
```

The info script will have the following output "output.txt" for each line:

```
FR  B000X2D ABC DEF GDI JKL
```

I have to find a string "DEF" and if it exists for the given code, I attach it to a line in the "input.txt" such that at the end it looks like this:

```
Country Code ID QTY TO_GO
    FR  B000X2D 75 130 DEF
```

If it does not exist, I delete this line completely.

Also I am not sure would it be easier to add the TO_GO info at the end of the "input.txt" or I should I create a new text file where I would combine info from "input.txt" and "output.txt"?

Comment: Where is the second file you mention in the title? Your code only seems to read from one file.

Comment: You can replace the first 11 lines by : `File.foreach('input.txt').drop(1).each do |line|`